# JMSContext injection cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jms, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I created a connectionFactory (qcf/cont) and a queue (queue/Impact)  on my websphere 
When I try to inject the connection factory in my message driven bean, I have this error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: The @Inject java.lang.reflect.Field.context reference of type javax.jms.JMSContext for the XXXXProducerBean component in the XXXEJB-5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar module of the XXXXServiceEAR application cannot be resolved.
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1154) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectableObject(InjectionBinding.java:1032) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject(InjectionTarget.java:125) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.inject(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:1084) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.initialize(StatelessBeanO.java:289) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:130) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createNewBeanO(EJSHome.java:869) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1242) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1360) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.UncachedActivationStrategy.atActivate(UncachedActivationStrategy.java:89) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.preInvokeActivateBean(Activator.java:324) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:3728) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3042) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
```

And my mdb looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Remote({ IXXXX.class })
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@DeclareRoles(Constants.USER_ROLE_NAME)
@RolesAllowed(Constants.USER_ROLE_NAME)
public class XXXXProducerBean implements IXXXX {

  @Inject
  @JMSConnectionFactory("qcf/cont")
  private JMSContext context;

  @Resource(name="queue/Impact")
  private Destination queueImpact;
```

I all docs I found on the Internet the JMSContext seems to get injected without any configuration... Is there something missing?

**EDIT**
Thanks for Eddie for the beans.xml file. I forgot It. 
But now I have an other exception:

```
[10/04/15 09:34:55:031 CEST] 0000006e BeansDeployer E BeansDeployer deploy 
                                 javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.jms.JMSContext] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into 
 Field Injection Point, field :  private javax.jms.JMSContext com.package.producer.ejb.XXXXProducerBean.context, Bean Owner : [WSEjbBean [businessLocals=[], ejbName=XXXXProducerBean2142018237,Name:null,WebBeans Type:ENTERPRISE,API Types:[java.lang.Object],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
     InjectionType   :  [interface javax.jms.JMSContext]
     Annotated       :  [Annotated Field,Base Type : interface javax.jms.JMSContext,Type Closures : [interface javax.jms.JMSContext, interface java.lang.AutoCloseable, class java.lang.Object],Annotations : [@javax.jms.JMSConnectionFactory(value=qcf/cont), @javax.inject.Inject()],Java Member Name : context]
     Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]]
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtils.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtils.java:92)
```

Comment: Do you have an empty `beans.xml` file under `WEB-INF`? You need one to [instantiate CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html) for EJB modules (JMS).

Comment: Thanks for the beans.xml file. Have you an idea for the new exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere supports JMS 1.1 not 2.0. The `@JMSConnectionFactory` is from 2.0. You need to change that to `@Resource` like this:

```
@Resource("qcf/cont")
  private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Comment: Right! It was a problem about WebSphere.

Comment: @bryce No, it was problem that you used unsupported API. You should always check if given api is supported on target runtime, or correctly configure your development environment, so it flags unknown classes. When I've pasted your sample to my environment it highlighted right away that `@JMSConnectionFactory` and `JMSContext` are unknown.

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I use these they were unknown. Then I added the dependency javax.jms-api and it worked...